# Spring Security Authentication object is null for Spring SseEmitter

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-security, server-sent-events

I have a Spring Controller method that invokes an SseEmitter to push server-sent events to browser. From the browser, javascript to create EventSource for the SSE url is run from the homepage. The homepage itself needs authentication that is done using Spring Security Form-based authentication. So a login page, on successful authentication, will direct to the home-page.However the authentication object is **null** in the Server-sent events method. I understand my incorrect Spring Security configuration is causing this but don't know how to fix it!!

Below is the security configuration I used

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class UCFSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("epUser")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
....
....
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.htm").failureUrl("/error.htm")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/spring_sec_auth.htm")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
            //.logoutSuccessUrl("/login.htm?logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and().csrf().disable();

}
....
....
}
```

> The SSE method below calls `userActivityFeed()` in
>   `UserActivityService` which uses Authentication object from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` which throws an **NPE**!!!

```
@Controller
public class UserActivityController {

@Autowired
private UserActivityService userActivityService;

@RequestMapping("/userActivity")
public ResponseBodyEmitter  activityFeed() {

    final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.execute(() -> {
       try {
            emitter.send(userActivityService.userActivityFeed() , MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            Thread.sleep(UCFConstants.USR_ACTV_REFRESH_PERIOD);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            emitter.completeWithError(e);
            return;
        }
        emitter.complete();
    });
    service.shutdown();
    return emitter;
  }
}
```

Javascript to create SSE EventSource object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var source = new EventSource("/MyApp/rest/userActivity");
 source.onmessage = function(event) {
                   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data                
                   + "<br>";
                   };
  </script>
```

My application web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` implementation. Under the hood it uses `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` strategy to hold your current security context. It means that current security context will be availible only from request thread. And your `userActivityFeed()` is actualy being executed in separate thread, that's why you're getting NPE when calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`.

To make all this work you can get current user earlier in controller method and pass it to `userActivityFeed()`.

Comment: Do you mean `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` doesn't get shared among requests in a session? I fail to understand then the point of a single entry-point authentication (e.g. login url ) if spring security-related objects (authentication, principal etc.) are not available to subsequent requests to restricted urls

Comment: As per spring docs, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html                       In an application which receives concurrent requests in a single session, the same SecurityContext instance will be shared between threads. Even though a ThreadLocal is being used, it is the same instance that is retrieved from the HttpSession for each thread. This has implications if you wish to temporarily change the context under which a thread is running.

Comment: The doc says about container threads that actually handles requests. But your `userActivityFeed()` method is being executed by executor service with it's own thread. This thread know nothing about SecurityContext